# In Spyder, how can I disable MRU (most recently used) behavior when switching between file tabs?

Tags: spyder, mru

In Spyder, how can I disable MRU (most recently used) behavior when switching between file tabs? I'd like the same behavior as in Chrome -- CTRL+TAB goes to the tab on the right, SHIFT+CTRL+TAB goes to the tab on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) That's simply not possible, sorry.